# force torque sensor and control force values

Tags: control, ros, gazebo, force, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I'm using libgazebo_ros_ft_sensor.so plugin to find torques in joints and control joints using [gazebo_ros_control](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_control) plugin. However when I compare joint torque from sensor and position_controller/state/command value (result of PID work), they are not the same. Their behaviour looks similar but as if sensor value n times smaller than command value. What could be the reason? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268979/force-torque-sensor-and-control-force-values/) by [RamilK](https://answers.ros.org/users/31594/ramilk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-08-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2017-08-16**:
units? proportional term?

**Comment by [RamilK](https://answers.ros.org/users/31594/ramilk/) on 2017-08-16**:
Sensor uses GetForceTorque function of gazebo which provides values in SI as I expect. ros_control generates effort as I understand and should be also in N*m. There are no multiplication factors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!
Seems that the solution is found! The issue was that i set high friction and damping coefficients in joint. As mentioned in [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/1321/proper-joint-torque-feedback), motor torque = joint torque + friction (static and dynamic damping). PID set motor torque by Joint::SetForce in Gazebo and joint effort limits its value (see [here](http://sdformat.org/spec?elem=joint)). As for ft_sensor, it shows joint torque value (motor torque - friction). So if we set friction to 0 (both static and dynamic) ft_sensor and PID values are identical. Or in case of joint effort limits effect ft_sensor value is cut.

---

Originally posted by [RamilK](https://answers.ros.org/users/31594/ramilk/) with karma: 26 on 2017-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1